# Joda DateTime: Parse date with "CEST" in string

Tags: java, scala, datetime, jodatime

I want to parse a DateTime using the joda library (in scala, but should be the same with java).

The source looks like

```
val dateParser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z")
val date = dateParser.parseDateTime("2012-08-28 15:35:00 CEST")
```

In Java this would look like

```
DateTimeFormatter dateParser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
DateTime date = dateParser.parseDateTime("2012-08-28 15:35:00 CEST");
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work but throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2012-08-28 15:35:00 CEST" is malformed at "CEST"
```

Why doesn't this work? Of course I could ignore the "CEST" part and just parse the rest, but in the input "CEST" can be replaced by "CET" sometimes, so I don't want to ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because `CEST` is a short zone name that is not unique. See the detailed discussion from [DateTimeFormatter Bug parsing with general time zones in US Locale?](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.joda-time.user/1385)

You can use the latest version from [github](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) that should contain a fix, see [this commit](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/commit/14863a51230b3d44201646dbc1ce5d7f6bb97a33).

You should be able to use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder#appendTimeZoneShortName` to add `CEST` as an alias for "America/Chicago" or to how you would like to interpret `CEST`.

Comment: Since "2012-08-28 15:35:00 PDT" is working, I think I already have the new version. Didn't see any mention of "CEST" or "CET" in the commit though. Is there a way to parse it nevertheless?

Comment: @Heinzi I assumed that you used the joda-time-2.1, that is not having this logic included yet. Note that with 2.1 `PDT` will not work. See my updated answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Apply parsing with a `java.util.Date`instance allows you to apply a workaround since `CEST` is not well parsing since not unique:

```
DateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(dateParser.parse("2012-08-28 15:35:00 CEST"));
//Here parsed `java.util.Date` instance is back to an instance of org.jodatime.DateTime`
```

Benefit of this workaround:  to not bother with "which version works with this timezone???"