# Parsing DateString to Date or DateTime

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime, jodatime

I am trying to make a Date or DateTime out of this String (which comes from a server):

```
Wed Oct 01 00:00:00 CEST 2014
```

I tried it the following ways, without success:

```
DateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date planDate = new DateTime(dateParser.parseObject("Wed Oct 01 00:00:00 CEST 2014"));
```

and

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
DateTime planDate = new DateTime(formatter.parseDateTime(""Wed Oct 01 00:00:00 CEST 2014""));
```

The first attempt throws a `ParseException` and the second one an `IllegalArgumentException` Invalid format. As I need to compare this `String` with a (Joda) `DateTime`, I really nee to parse it.

Comment: You need to edit your question or tags and let everyone know what type of server/shell and language you are attempting to use. It makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case you miss the locale:

```
DateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

For second problem see:: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181970/joda-datetime-parse-date-with-cest-in-string?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date planDate =dateParser.parse("Wed Oct 01 00:00:00 CEST 2014");
```