# How to convert a string to data field in logstash filter plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm new to ELK stack. exploring logstash and elastic search for the last one week. I'm finding difficulties to convert a time stamp(default considered as string type) to date type field.
This the string "Thu May 18 06:39:44 CEST 2017" represents timestamp in tool log wanted to convert this string to date field using logstash filter Date plugin.  I don't know how to make it. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated. Thanks !

```
filter {    
 csv {     
    columns =>["Make","Color","Price","Sold"]     
    separator =>","       
 }       
date
{      
match => ["Sold", "DD-MM-YYYY"] #  Not sure how to match timestamp in log file to convert to date type.        
target => "Sold"      
}      
mutate{      
   convert => ["Price","float"]    
   }      
 }
```

//Let's assume My csv file contains the below logs. the last field for timestamp
iPhone,silver,260,Thu Sep 07 11:05:07 CEST 2017

iPhone,gold,400,Thu Oct 07 12:05:07 CEST 2017

Comment: Show some of your efforts first.

Comment: Share your logstash config file.

Comment: @HatimStovewala . Thanks for your reply. pls find the config file.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match

Comment: `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss \`CEST\` yyyy` I haven't tested it. Note that the EEE and MMM are locale-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your Index first by below command. (... replace it with your rest of the columns and their type. Refer Elasticsearch [Put Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html))

```
PUT date
{
  "mappings": {
    "date": {
      "properties": {
        ...,
        "TimeStamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can go ahead with logstash to push data into ES. Remove the date filter from logstash config file. ES will parse the string into date.

Note : While testing it with sample data, I realised that `CEST` is not accepted as a timezone. I guess you will need to replace CEST with CST. There is some issue with this kind of parsing, [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181970/joda-datetime-parse-date-with-cest-in-string/13182191#13182191).

If the timezone is fixed to CEST in your data then you can do this work around:

```
PUT date
{
  "mappings": {
    "date": {
      "properties": {
        ...,
        "TimeStamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'CEST' yyyy"
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```