# Invalid format: "2019-05-10 18:45:00 CEST+0200" is malformed at "CEST+0200"

Tags: java, android, jodatime

Can't convert this date format with joda time to localtime

I am already using the newest `joda` version 2.10.1 and I have tried many solutions by changing the format or adding locale but neither works.

```
val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zZ").toFormatter()
        return dateTimeFormatter.withLocale(Locale.GERMANY).parseDateTime("2019-05-10 18:45:00 CEST+0200")
```

The question mentioned in the comments below is not a good reference to consider my question as a duplicate  because the answers there don't help with the issue really .

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181970/joda-datetime-parse-date-with-cest-in-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joda DateTime: Parse date with "CEST" in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181970/joda-datetime-parse-date-with-cest-in-string)

Comment: Having a pattern with both a zone id and an offset doesn't make much sense. What is the source of this string?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Customer webservice endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing `CEST` from time string and just using the offset(+0200) and It works great with `java.time` and `jodatime`.
I've notice something interesting though, that there is a diffrence how `java.time` and `jodatime` handels date patterns.
For Example the following date string `2019-05-10 18:45:00 CEST+0200` and the following pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ` will work in `java.time` but won't in `jodatime`, but with the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` they both would understand the date content.